# does otherwise fit in this sentence

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality, meaning-in-context, vocabulary

I am writing a mathematical report  and i wrote this:

> In the following sections, the value of x is always 1 unless it is stated the otherwise.

Did I use **otherwise** correctly here please ?

Thanks for helping guys

Answer (score 1):

No, it reads better as:

"the value of x is always 1 unless otherwise stated"

it would also work as

"the value of x is always 1 unless stated otherwise"

I can see why the use of "the otherwise", the use here is an adjective, however "otherwise" the word effectively means "the alternative" and so is typically used standalone.

Comment: 'Otherwise' literally means 'other ways'.  It is not definite because 'the other way' is not given.

Comment: Drop the "always." You don't need it and it's confusing.